# Creating an RGB picture in Python with OpenCV from a randomized array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to create a RGB image made from a random array of pixel values in Python with OpenCV/Numpy setup.

I'm able to create a Gray image - which looks amazingly live; with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

pic_array=np.random.randint(255, size=(900,800))
pic_array_8bit=slika_array.astype(np.uint8)
pic_g=cv2.imwrite("pic-from-random-array.png", pic_array_8bit)
```

But I want to make it in color as well. I've tried converting with cv2.cvtColor() but it couldnt work.

The issue might be in an array definition or a missed step. Couldn't find a similar situation... Any help how to make a random RGB image in color, would be great.

thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

RGB image is composed of three grayscale images. You can make three grayscale images like

```
rgb = np.random.randint(255, size=(900,800,3),dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('RGB',rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define a random image data consisting of 3 channels using numpy as shown below-

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(900, 800, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Now use, python imaging library as shown below-

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

You can also save the image easily using `save` function

```
img.save('image.png')
```

Comment: OP asks about OpenCV, why bring in PIL?